# Mybatis: no Result Maps were found for the Mapped Statement

Tags: mybatis

I had to add a ping query to ensure db did not timeout, to existing mapper files and code, this looks as follows:

In the mapper XML:

```
<select id="pingTest" statementType="CALLABLE">
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
</select>
```

Interface:

```
void pingTest() throws SQLException;
```

Implementation (inside LogInputDao class):

```
    public void pingTest() throws SQLException {
    SqlSession session = null;

    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = MyBatisDBConfig.getSqlSessionFactory();

    session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

    LogInputMapper mapper = session.getMapper(LogInputMapper.class);
    mapper.pingTest();
}
```

logInputDao.pingTest()

Brings out the error:

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: A query was run and no Result Maps were found for the Mapped Statement 'com.example.proj.name.dbservice.mappers.LogInputMapper.pingTest'.  It's likely that neither a Result Type nor a Result Map was specified.
### The error may exist in com/example/proj/dbservice/config/LogInputMapper.xml
### The error may involve defaultParameterMap
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.executor.ExecutorException: A query was run and no Result Maps were found for the Mapped Statement 'com.example.proj.name.dbservice.mappers.LogInputMapper.pingTest'.  It's likely that neither a Result Type nor a Result Map was specified.
        at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:95)
        at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:59)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
        at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.pingTest(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.proj.name.dbservice.dao.LogInputDao.pingTest(LogInputDao.java:52)
.....
```

I dont need the results, either way I am not sure exactly how to fix this, first time I do something with MyBatis

Comment: Remove `statementType="CALLABLE"` and add `resultType="_int"` instead (the mapper method also has to return `int`). Even if you don't use the result, MyBatis still has to know what to return. Note that connection validation is usually done by a connection pool implementation.

Comment: Thanks @ave! That did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

As [@ave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1261766/ave) said already above,
in `select` statements MyBatis expects some data to return and it needs to map it.
One of them is necessary.
So you have to add a `resultType` or `resultMap` tag and remove unnecessary `statementType="CALLABLE"`.

Here is an example of mapping:

```
<select id="pingTest" resultType="int">
    SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
</select>
```